# Why ldd doesn't show filename paths for dependencies?

Tags: dynamic-linking, ld

I'm experimenting with ELF `RUNPATH` variable for dynamic dependencies. Along the way I got a copy of `bash` binary with changed `RUNPATH`, running `ldd` on it returns:

```
$ ldd ./bash 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe6bdf9000)
    libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fbf8b97c000)
    libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbf8b776000)
    libc.so.6 (0x00007fbf8b3a5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbf8bba7000)
```

-- why aren't there paths to the dependencies (from my custom `RUNPATH`) or `not found`, what does it mean?

My guess would be:
`ldd` cannot find the files, but they are in memory (numbers in parentheses are the addresses), and `ldd` gets to know about it somehow, via some cash-mechanism, is it correct? But then how come `ldd` doesn't find files? If it fails to fetch them from `RUNPATH`, it should proceed to standard directories, right?

## Update

Today it finds the files (so it were the cashes yesterday?):

```
$ cd dir_chroot2/
$ ldd ./bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffed3530000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /home/.../dir_chroot2/./libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f72c14a8000)
    libdl.so.2 => /home/.../dir_chroot2/./libdl.so.2 (0x00007f72c12a1000)
    libc.so.6 => /home/.../dir_chroot2/./libc.so.6 (0x00007f72c0ed0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f72c16d4000)
```

-- but `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is still fetched from system directory, though `bash` binary and all libraries above it have `RUNPATH=$ORIGIN/`. Why is it so? Does `linux-vdso.so.1` link it somehow?